LinkedIn API: Consistent 500 Internal Server Errors When Retrieving Organizational Entity Statistics and Followers data
I am encountering Internal Server Error (HTTP status code 500) when attempting to retrieve organizational entity statistics and followers using the LinkedIn API. The organization URN is 12668855. Below are the details of the issue:
Endpoints:

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=%7Borganization_URN%7D
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=%7Borganization_URN%7D

Error Response:
{
"message": "Internal Server Error",
"status": 500
}
Expected Outcome:
I expect to receive valid statistical and follwers data for the specified organizational entity
Additional Information:
I have already contacted LinkedIn support, and they suggested posting this issue on Stack Overflow for further assistance.
Python code I am using :
import os

import requests

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')

ORGANIZATION_ID = os.getenv('ORGANIZATION_ID')

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}',
    'LinkedIn-Version': '202405',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version':'2.0.0'
}

url_1 = f'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={ORGANIZATION_ID}'

url_2 =f"https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={ORGANIZATION_ID}"

shares_response = requests.get(url=url_1, headers=headers)

shares_data = shares_response.json()

print(shares_data)

followers_response = requests.get(url=url_2,headers=headers)

follwers_data = followers_response.json()

print(follwers_data)


**Output I am getting :**

{'message': 'Internal Server Error', 'status': 500}

{'message': 'Internal Server Error', 'status': 500}

Expected Outcome :
 Expected to receive valid statistical data and followers data for the specified organizational entity

Document referred for APIs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?view=li-lms-2024-05&tabs=http

Here is my code that works.
# Define the endpoint URL for follower statistics

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?'

# Set the headers
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {linkedin_api_accesstoken}',
    'Linkedin-Version': version
}

# Set the parameters
params = {
    'q': 'organizationalEntity',
    'organizationalEntity': organization_id
}


# Make the GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
print(f"Status Code: {response.status_code}")


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
